# Are there closed/deleted questions on SO that you guys actually want over here?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I'm trying hard to avoid using Programmers as the new and improved dumping ground for unwanted SO questions, but the flags keep coming.  Right now the question [How to handle people who lie on their resume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566662/how-to-handle-people-who-lie-on-their-resume) is close to being resurrected, and there's a request in the queue to migrate it to Programmers.  This is clearly off-topic for SO, but I'm not sure if it will just get closed here as well.  Do you guys want questions like this, or should I kill it with fire?

Comment: Would it be possible for someone to run a query on how many question have been migrated from SO and how many are actually still open?  Might be a useful bit of information for working out whether migration is working.

Comment: Grrr, someone [sent it over](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/39302/how-to-handle-people-who-lie-on-their-resume). I'm going to steal all of your garden gnomes!

Comment: @TimPost: That's my fault.  I should have flagged it to let the other SO mods know that I was checking downstream before making a decision.  Sorry.

Comment: It's funny because I was looking at the deletion queue and saw that one getting votes to undelete. I immediately said to myself "I bet they're gonna send that to programmers SE". No worries.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an historical artifact that shouldn't garner any more activity.

Answer (score 4):

It seems awfully generic to me -- how is "guy who lies on his resume" specific to programming versus any other profession?

The answers (the top two voted ones anyway) don't strike me as particularly programmer-specific, either.

Note that in the general case my criteria for preservation is:

> if a question has no *lasting and permanent value*, it should be **deleted**.

Comment: It _was_ deleted, I just saw it get _undeleted_ then almost immediately shipped here :/

Answer (score 1):

If you can make it significantly programmer specific I don't see why not. I believe it would be a good question along the vein of they put a buzzword on paper but can't clearly define it or really understand what it is. [Similar to the agile buzzword question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/36925/weeding-out-real-agile-from-buzzword-agile-in-an-interview).

Answer (score 1):

I would be very reluctant to migrate old questions. This one is nearly **two year's old**.

It would be far better to keep it closed (and even locked) on Stack Overflow.

In this case I've added a note to the question over here, but might have to lock it if it gets too much bad attention.